# Windows 7 fails to detect the native resolution of LG Flatron W1934S

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I connected a LG Flatron W1934S LCD using VGA Cable to a PC which had Win 7 already installed. Now my problem is that Win 7 fails to detect the native resolution of the monitor which is 1440 x 900 at 75 Hz.

The monitor is detected as generic non-PnP monitor.  I tried reinstalling graphics drivers (Intel Express G33 / G31) with the monitor connected. No use.

I also tried uninstalling current monitor drivers and rebooted the machine in the hope that the monitor will be detected. No Use.

I couldn’t find a driver on LG’s website (horrible usability). Can anyone guide me how can I get the OS to detect the native resolution of the monitor?

Thanks & Regards,
Pritam.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the driver for Vista for W1934S-BN ?:

http://www.lg.com/us/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=W1934S-BN&matchedModelCode=NOT_MATCHED&searchEngineModelCode=W1934S-BN&initialTab=documents&targetPage=support-product-profile

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop and choose `Screen Resolution`.

You can manually change it there.

Sometimes auto detection just doesn't work - it isn't a problem and manually changing does not damage or affect usage in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some VGA cables don't allow for automatic detection of the monitor.  You might try a different cable or try plugging it into a different computer with that same cable and see if it is recognized.